# Determinant as a scalar dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, analytic-geometry

Consider the following product:

$$\langle A | B \rangle=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{01} | b_{00} & b_{01} \\ 
a_{10} & a_{11} | b_{10} & b_{11} \\
\end{bmatrix} 
=
 a_{00} b_{11} - b_{01} a_{10} - a_{01} b_{10} + b_{00} a_{11}
$$

this product has interesting properties, one of them is that:

$$
\det(A) = 1/2 \langle A | A \rangle
$$

But I think the most appealing property is that allows a relationship of distributivity of determinants:

$$
\det(A + B) = \langle A + B | A + B  \rangle = \langle A A \rangle + 2 \langle A B \rangle + \langle B B \rangle = 2 \det(A) + 2 \det(B) + 2 \langle A B \rangle
$$

Written in alternative form:

$$
\langle A B \rangle = \frac{\det(A + B)}{2} - \det(A) - \det(B)
$$

Can this product be generalized to higher than $2 \times 2$ matrices, such that both interesting properties are preserved?

> **Disclaimer:** I was about to ask this question in Physics.SE instead, since algebraic bra-ket *know-how* typically lies on a kind of gray area of
>   ownership in the boundaries between physics history and mathematics traditional
>   training, nonetheless and against my best judgment I decided to post the question
>   here

Comment: I think your product can be written as
$$
\langle A|B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(A^TKBK^T)
$$
where
$$
K = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom is there a way to generalize that expression for $N \times N$ matrices?

Answer (score 2):

The "distributivity" propriety you noticed is simply because the determinant of a 2x2 matrix is a quadratic form. Basically the map $\widetilde{\det}$ defined as :

$$\widetilde{\det}(A,B)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\det(A+B)-\det(A)-\det(B)\right)$$
is bilinear symmetric. You can easily check it matches your bilinear form. It may be called the polar form of $\det$. It follows that :

$$\widetilde{\det}(A,A)=\det(A)$$
$$\det(A+B)=\widetilde{\det}(A+B,A+B)=\det(A)+\widetilde{\det}(A,B)+\widetilde{\det}(B,A)+\det(B)$$

I'm not sure it generalizes in a helpful way. The distributivity looks nice, but $\widetilde{\det}$ is defined from the determinant anyways and, as far as I know, it wouldn't really simplify expressions involving the determinant of a sum of a matrix.